# wanted CSS property: line separator above heading

Tags: html, css

I've been looking for a way to define CSS heading properties so that I get a short coloured line a few pixels above the heading text. I do not want a top border, as that stretches all the way across the page.

The various border, outline, background and other properties seem to have no way of specifying length, such as a percentage or number of pixels.

The various CSS techniques for creating standalone separators seem to require a block of code on their own, e.g. a class or id.

For the moment I am using the inline-block and background color properties to create something somewhat similar to what I'm after. But it would be nice to know if there's a way of creating the equivalent of a top border with a length of my own choosing.

Comment: Please add in your code of the current way of doing this, like http://jsfiddle.net/45txe2no/ ?

Comment: There is no current way. But thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use pseudo-selectors.

```css
h1:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 1px;
  width: 50px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<h1>Sample title</h1>
```

Comment: Aha! news to me. I can see it works just fine here. I'm attempting to use it in a wiki-editor that seems to dislike the pseudo classes & selectors. So it doesn't work in that context. But it certainly answers my question!

Comment: It's possible they're using the selectors for a different purpose in which case you might get away with just overriding them.

Comment: The answer I got from the wiki developer is that CSS2 is not fully implemented. So am still looking for solutions, but not expecting any!